# Mongoid embedded keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I've got a `Tag` model:

```
class Tag
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :taggable, :polymorphic => true

  key :title
  field :title, :type => String
end
```

Before this model was `embedded_in`, having `key :title` forced the id to be based on the title. For some reason now that it's embedded, the ids go back to things like `4fb42e1f5d9a1e68f100000d`. Any ideas how to have the key be based on the title?

Comment: Maybe a bug in mongoid? Have you tried looking at the sources?

Comment: What exact version of Mongoid are you using?

Comment: @GaryMurakami I'm using version 2.4.9 according to my Gemfile.lock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can get ids specified by key with what you have specified, exactly.
Maybe you have a problem with your encapsulating model that you didn't share?
The following works for me with Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.3, Mongoid 2.4.9.

```
class Item
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_many :tags, as: :taggable

  key :name
  field :name, :type => String
end
```

test/unit/tag_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class TagTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    Item.delete_all
    #Tag.delete_all
  end

  test "key title" do
    item = Item.create(name: 'book')
    assert_equal(1, Item.count)
    assert_equal('book', Item.where(name: 'book').first[:_id])
    tag = Tag.new(title: 'scifi')
    item.tags << tag
    assert_equal('scifi', Item.where(name: 'book').first.tags.first[:_id])
    puts Item.all.to_a.first.to_json
  end
end
```

test output

```
Run options: --name=test_key_title

# Running tests:

{"_id":"book","name":"book","tags":[{"_id":"scifi","title":"scifi"}]}
.

Finished tests in 0.010775s, 92.8074 tests/s, 278.4223 assertions/s.

1 tests, 3 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out based on what you wrote. The problem was with how the tags were being created. If I did `tag = Tag.new` and then on the next line `tag.title = "some title"`, that's when the issues occur. If I do it on one line, `tag = Tag.new(title: "some title")` then everything is perfect. Guess it's because it has to have the `_id` at creation time...